# Python freezes on simple file read and print

Tags: python, windows, windows-server-2012

Im having an issue with a pretty simple piece of code. i have a file of 6551 lines(ASCII), and all i've managed to do so far is to read the file and print it.

```
a_file = open(myfile_path).readlines()
print a_file
```

upon trying to print, the interpreter gets completely stuck for a few minutes.
i've tried this both in idle and in jetbrains pycharm. im runnning windows server 2012 as my work work station and windows 7 at home - funny thing is that this worked perfectly on the weaker windows 7 machine back home(q9550 and 8gb ram) - but i cant(and neither the it guy) find a solution for this on my work station(i7 on x99, 64gb ram, gtx980).

would appreciate all and any assistance.

Comment: Why do you need to print the file?  Printing that many lines is always going to be inefficient.

Comment: at this time in the code, i just wanted to see that it loaded, thats when i came across this strange problem. i've printed larger files before as a debug print, of course i dont intend to use it in the final result

Comment: It doesn't matter if you've printed bigger files. Perhaps you were running more/less/different progs at that time vs. now? Perhaps things were just slightly different. In any case the way your going about opening/reading the file inefficiently for the very reasons you describe. You can easily be done better using the method below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to read a file to memory (that's what you do) exactly because you can face problems you encountered with.

If you want to print every line of the file, you can use the following construction:

```
with open(myfile_path) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        print line
```

for more complicated actions you (or the IT-guy) should better address to [the documentation for open() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) and file operations.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to the punch. Couldn't have said/written it better my self.

Answer (score 0):

First, try this:

```
import sys

with open(myfile_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        print f
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

It could be a number of things causing the script to hang such as the file being open or locked or the output blocking.  This will cause everything that can print to print.

Additionally, generally doing things a line at a time is beneficial unless you actually need all of the lines at the same time in a list  This shouldn't be the root cause here unless the line lengths are truly enormous but it's good style to not allocate giant data structures.

Additionally, setting non-blocking mode on the file will resolve issues such as the file being written to and locked (though this *won't* give you a solution that is stable but it will stop blocking on read instead).  This is OS dependent and probably won't help you more than it will hurt.

If the issue is that the file is being written to (I've come across this a lot in Windows), another option is to copy the file being written to into a temp file and handing that copy to the script.

What you choose to do will depend greatly on whether you want to ensure you have all the data possible or whether you want to ensure the script runs immediately.