# Program crashes during reading text file

Tags: python

```
def process_file(self):
        error_flag = 0
        line_count = 0
        log_file = self.file_name
        pure_name = log_file.strip()
        # print('Before opening file ',pure_name)
        logfile_in = open(pure_name, 'r')  # Read file

        lines = logfile_in.readlines()
        # print('After reading file enteries ', pure_name)
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\BackupLogCheck\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    backupLogs.process_file()
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\BackupLogCheck\main.py", line 20, in process_file
    lines = logfile_in.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 350: character maps to <undefined>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Line 49 is where I call above method. But I have traced that it crashes at reading the file. I have checked the file; it has just text in it. I don't know if there are some characters which it doesn't like on reading entries. I am running on Windows 10.
I am new to Python, any suggestion how to find/correct the issue?

Comment: Maybe try setting the encoding?

Comment: please provide the error thrown by the program

Comment: Yes, please provide the _full traceback_ - and put it in your post, not in a comment.

Comment: As above comments, provide detailed error message than just saying it crashes. Have you checked the value of the variable `pure_name` does it point to a valid path to the file that you are trying to read? which OS are you running on, check if the program running has access permission to read that file. there could be many reasons.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete code (`pure_name` is not defined), any example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: By the way, how large is your file that you are trying to load, if it is too large to fit in memory, you could see your process crash. see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388839/python-freezes-on-simple-file-read-and-print)

Comment: I have provided more code. Also, what is a better way to read large file? This program works file for lot of other files but just doesn't for some files. The file is itself 28kb only.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's saying the file contains a `0x90` byte, which is undefined in the CP-1252 codec. So you'll need to specify a different encoding to read the file, or read it as binary if that would work for you. There's still not enough context here for me to say conclusively. Again, you need to make a [mre].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487563/unicode-error-handling-with-python-3s-readlines

Answer (score -2):

Try the file name in string format

```
logfile_in = open('pure_name', 'r')  # Read file
lines = logfile_in.readlines()

print(lines)
```

output

```
['test line one\n', 'test line two']
```

or

```
logfile_in = open('pure_name', 'r')  # Read file
lines = logfile_in.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

output

```
test line one

test line two
```

Comment: open('pure_name', 'r') - huh,  how come this will read a file, are you assuming the name of the file itself is 'pure_name' that the OP is trying to read!

Comment: yes I create a file with the name pure_name and it read it normally

Comment: the file I was created simply in text format

Comment: Appreciate your interest to answer, but that is not the problem for the OP's code - there a variable has the file path which is passed as input argument to `open()` function.